# SQL Server 2008 login issue using Active Directory users

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sir i installed sql server 2008 in one domain i can login sql server in both login mode.Is it possible to login sql server from diffrent domain?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you have a trust relationship between your domains that will allow users from the other domain to authenticate to resources in the domain that holds the SQL server. The domain with the SQL server would need to have at least a one-way outgoing trust to the other domain.  You would also still need to add the relevant Active Directory users from the other domain into the SQL server Security, to allow authentication.